# R table manipulation

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I have a data.frame as below

```
PRODUCT=c(rep("A",4),rep("B",2))
ww1=c(201438,201440,201444,201446,201411,201412)
ww2=ww1-6
DIFF=rep(6,6)
DEMAND=rep(100,6)

df=data.frame(PRODUCT,ww1,ww2,DIFF,DEMAND)
df<- df[with(df,order(PRODUCT, ww1)),]

df

  PRODUCT    ww1    ww2 DIFF DEMAND
1       A 201438 201432    6    100
2       A 201440 201434    6    100
3       A 201444 201438    6    100
4       A 201446 201440    6    100
5       B 201411 201405    6    100
6       B 201412 201406    6    100
```

I want to add rows to it based upon the conditions below.

For any row in the data, if the product on the earlier row is the same as the product on the current row, but the ww1 on the earlier row is not same as the ww1-1 on the current row (basically ww1 difference is 1), then add a new row.

For the newly added row:

```
Product will be the same as product on earlier row.
ww1 will be ww1 on the earlier row + 1
ww2 will be ww2 on the earlier row + 1
ww_diff will be 6
demand will be 0
```

The final output that I need is something like below:

```
PRODUCT ww1 ww2 WW_DIFF DEMAND
A   201438  201432  6   100
A   201439  201433  6   0
A   201440  201434  6   100
A   201441  201435  6   0
A   201442  201436  6   100
A   201443  201437  6   0
A   201444  201438  6   100
A   201445  201439  6   0
A   201446  201440  6   100
B   201411  201405  6   100
B   201412  201406  6   100
```

As of now I am thinking of writing a macro in excel, but it will be very slow and therefore I would prefer a R solution

update1===============================

How could I add column seq? that column is 1 for earliest entry of ww1 of every product and then it increments by 1.

```
PRODUCT ww1 ww2 WW_DIFF DEMAND  seq
A   201438  201432  6   100 1
A   201439  201433  6   0   2
A   201440  201434  6   100 3
A   201441  201435  6   0   4
A   201442  201436  6   100 5
A   201443  201437  6   0   6
A   201444  201438  6   100 7
A   201445  201439  6   0   8
A   201446  201440  6   100 9
B   201411  201405  6   100 1
B   201412  201406  6   100 2
```

update2=======================================================

I am posting questions again (I unchecked previously accepted answer of alistaire as that answer is not working on my original data, it works only on small sample of data :(

In below solution by user alistaire, `df3 <- right_join(df, data.frame(ww1=ww1big))` seem to be causing issue.

In a final solution, I would also prefer if columns are specified by their names. That way I won't be forced to arrange columns in a particular order.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't filtering the data rather than adding the data to a df?

Comment: I didnt get you? I want to add those rows as they are not available currently. How would filtering solve my issue?

Comment: Is the table `df`ordered first by `PRODUCT` and then by `ww1`?

Comment: @Stibu yes. You are correct

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is my answer valid for your purposes or has it some issue I have not contemplated? In my opinion, it is impolite  that after taking my time to answer your question, you do not even reply telling me that something is wrong or that it does not properly fit your needs especially when you have posted other comments. I think these kinds of behaviours discourage people from answering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a very similar `data.table` solution that I assume should be more efficient as I'm minimizing the calculations per group and using *binary* join instead.

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df), PRODUCT, ww1) ## Sorting by `PRODUCT` and `ww1`
indx <- setkey(df[, list(ww1 = seq.int(ww1[1L], ww1[.N], by = 1L)), by = PRODUCT]) ## running `seq.int` on `ww1` per group
res <- df[indx][is.na(ww2), `:=`(ww2 = ww1 - 6L, DIFF = 6L, DEMAND = 0L)] ## filling the missing values
res[, seq := seq_len(.N), by = PRODUCT] # Adding index
res
#     PRODUCT    ww1    ww2 DIFF DEMAND seq
#  1:       A 201438 201432    6    100   1
#  2:       A 201439 201433    6      0   2
#  3:       A 201440 201434    6    100   3
#  4:       A 201441 201435    6      0   4
#  5:       A 201442 201436    6      0   5
#  6:       A 201443 201437    6      0   6
#  7:       A 201444 201438    6    100   7
#  8:       A 201445 201439    6      0   8
#  9:       A 201446 201440    6    100   9
# 10:       B 201411 201405    6    100   1
# 11:       B 201412 201406    6    100   2
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the instructions, you'd still have gaps in `ww1` if there is more than one missing value in a row. Nevertheless, you can follow the stated logic exactly like this:

```
require(dplyr)

df2 <- rbind(df,
         unique(do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(nrow(df)), function(x){
             toAdd <- filter(df[1:x-1,], PRODUCT == df[x, 'PRODUCT'], ww1 != df[x,'ww1']-1)
             if(nrow(toAdd) > 0){
                 toAdd$ww1 <- toAdd$ww1+1
                 toAdd$ww2 <- toAdd$ww2+1
                 toAdd$DEMAND <- 0
                 toAdd
             }
         })))
)
```

which returns

```
> df2

  PRODUCT    ww1    ww2 DIFF DEMAND
1       A 201438 201432    6    100
2       A 201439 201433    6      0
3       A 201440 201434    6    100
4       A 201441 201435    6      0
5       A 201444 201438    6    100
6       A 201445 201439    6      0
7       A 201446 201440    6    100
8       B 201411 201405    6    100
9       B 201412 201406    6    100
```

If, on the other hand, you want rows for every value of `ww1` between the min and max for each product, this will work:

```
require(dplyr)

df <- group_by(df, PRODUCT)
extremes <- summarise(df, maxw=max(ww1), minw=min(ww1))
ww1big <- do.call(c, lapply(seq(nrow(extremes)), function(x){
    seq(extremes[[x, 3]], extremes[[x, 2]])
}))

df3 <- right_join(df, data.frame(ww1=ww1big))
nullindex <- seq_along(df3$PRODUCT)[is.na(df3$PRODUCT)]

# the `for` and `while` loops will be slow if the dataset is REALLY huge, but they're pretty simple
nullreplace <- nullindex
for(i in 1:length(nullreplace)){
    while(is.na(df3[nullreplace[i], 1])){
        nullreplace[i]<-nullreplace[i]-1
    }
}
df3[nullindex, c(1, 4)] <- df3[nullreplace, c(1, 4)]
df3[nullindex, 5] <- 0
df3[nullindex, 3] <- df3[nullreplace, 3] + (nullindex-nullreplace)
```

which returns:

```
> df3
Source: local data frame [11 x 5]
Groups: PRODUCT

   PRODUCT    ww1    ww2 DIFF DEMAND
1        A 201438 201432    6    100
2        A 201439 201433    6      0
3        A 201440 201434    6    100
4        A 201441 201435    6      0
5        A 201442 201436    6      0
6        A 201443 201437    6      0
7        A 201444 201438    6    100
8        A 201445 201439    6      0
9        A 201446 201440    6    100
10       B 201411 201405    6    100
11       B 201412 201406    6    100
```

Both solutions make use of the `dplyr` package, and neither is terribly elegant. They should both be fast, though, aside from the one `for`/`while` loop in the second selection, which is relatively simple. It could probably be rewritten with an `*apply` function if necessary, though it will be less readable. Both can handle additional products easily.

edit 1=========================

It's super easy, actually, because the `data.frame` is already grouped by product by `dplyr`, so all you need is

```
df3 <- mutate(df3, seq=seq_along(PRODUCT))
```

and you get

```
> df3
Source: local data frame [11 x 6]
Groups: PRODUCT

   PRODUCT    ww1    ww2 DIFF DEMAND seq
1        A 201438 201432    6    100   1
2        A 201439 201433    6      0   2
3        A 201440 201434    6    100   3
4        A 201441 201435    6      0   4
5        A 201442 201436    6      0   5
6        A 201443 201437    6      0   6
7        A 201444 201438    6    100   7
8        A 201445 201439    6      0   8
9        A 201446 201440    6    100   9
10       B 201411 201405    6    100   1
11       B 201412 201406    6    100   2
```

Comment: thanks :). For my actual data, I am planning to name columns as in the original question. I will also sort my data by Product and then within product by ww1. Would that be sufficient to run your scripts? Are you making any other assumptions? do i have to maintain sequence of columns?

Comment: Again, sorting is easy with `dplyr`; just run `df3 <- arrange(df3, PRODUCT, ww1)`. Sequence of columns doesn't matter, but you do need to make sure you have `dplyr` installed first. `install.packages(dplyr)` should do the trick, as long as R knows where a CRAN mirror is. Hadley wrote a nice [vignette](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) if you need to do more.

Comment: Oops, actually the second solution does depend on column order. To make it order-independent, just replace the integers in subsets with the name of the column in quotations (or `$` notation).

Comment: I didnt get you :(. Would it be possible to update your second solution. I use that only...

Comment: @allistaire i am adding a new column to my data based upon the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30553282/r-text-manipulation. Instead of column ww1, I want df$newww1 to be the column on which all calculations that you were doing above to work. But i am getting an error. Would it be possible to amend your solution to do the same? I get error in the 2nd statement below `extremes <- summarise(df, maxw=max(newww1), minw=min(newww1))`
`ww1big <- do.call(c, lapply(seq(nrow(extremes)), function(x){
    seq(extremes[[x, 3]], extremes[[x, 2]])
})) `

Comment: error is :  `Error in seq.default(extremes[[x, 3]], extremes[[x, 2]]) : 
  'from' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite`

Comment: i tried it on my huge dataset and it is not producing what is expected :(

Comment: Do you have `NA` or `NaN` values in the `ww1` column?

Comment: Making it column-order independent is easy; just replace the integers in subsetting brackets (`[]`) with the column name in quotes. [See here.](https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/free-introduction-to-r/chapter-5-data-frames?ex=7) About the extra column, I'd just run this script first, then the other, so you don't need to edit either.

Comment: I figured out that the problem occurs at right join. ww1big data frame doesn't have product column. In such case, if multiple products span over common weeks then it creates one to many join. The problem should get solved if we add product column to ww1big and then join two tables on product and ww

Comment: Can you update the data above with the new column so I can see what you're starting with? Alternately, as I said before, running this script before the one that adds the other column should avoid the join error.

Answer (score 3):

I lately have to use big tables and have become a great fan of data.table package (it is really fast and allows creating new variables without allocating memory).

With it the solution would be as follows:

```
library(data.table)

# convert to data.table
dtable = as.data.table(df)
# create the variables grouped by PRODUCT 
dtransf <- dtable[, .(ww1 = seq(min(ww1), max(ww1), 1L), 
                      ww2 = seq(min(ww2), max(ww2), 1L), 
                     DIFF = 6L,
                   DEMAND = as.integer(seq(min(ww1), max(ww1),1L) %in% unique(ww1)) * 100), 
                 by = PRODUCT]
#add the incremental counter
dtransf[,seq := seq_len(.N), by = PRODUCT]
```

The code is a bit case specific (especially the DEMAND calculation), in a more complex situation you will probably need some join for inputing the right demand. 
Also, bare in mind that if there is some error in the dataset (for instance a ww1 and ww2 not having the same difference between elements) the code will fail.

Answer (score 1):

```
# NEW SOLUTION
nrows = length(df[,1])
newdf = df[1,]
myseq = 1
for(i in 2:nrows) {
  currentRow = df[i,]
  tmpRow = df[i-1,]

  if(tmpRow$ww1 < (currentRow$ww1 - 1)) {
    tmp = (tmpRow$ww1+1):(currentRow$ww1-1)
    tmp.length = length(tmp)
    tmp.last = ifelse(length(myseq)==0, 1, tail(myseq,1)+1) 
    myseq = c(myseq, tmp.last:(tmp.last + tmp.length))
    tmpdf = data.frame(PRODUCT=rep(tmpRow$PRODUCT, tmp.length),
     ww1=tmp, ww2=tmp-6, DIFF=rep(6,tmp.length),DEMAND=rep(0,tmp.length))
    newdf = rbind(newdf,tmpdf,currentRow)
  } else {
    if(tmpRow$ww1==currentRow$ww1-1) {
      myseq = c(myseq, tail(myseq,1)+1)
    } else {
      myseq = c(myseq,1)
    }
    newdf = rbind(newdf,currentRow)
  }
}
newdf = cbind(newdf, myseq)
nrows = length(newdf[,1])
row.names(newdf) = 1:nrows    

# OLD SOLUTION
nrows = length(df[,1])
newdf = df[1,]
for(i in 2:nrows) {
  previousRow = df[i-1,] 
  currentRow = df[i,]
  tmpRow = df[i-1,]

  if(tmpRow$ww1 < currentRow$ww1) {
    while(tmpRow$ww1 + 1 != currentRow$ww1) {
      tmpRow$ww1 = tmpRow$ww1 + 1
      tmpRow$ww2 = tmpRow$ww2 + 1 
      # diff doesn't change
      tmpRow$DEMAND = 0
      # rbind current row
      newdf=rbind(newdf,tmpRow)
    }
  }
  newdf=rbind(newdf,currentRow)
}
nrows = length(newdf[,1])
row.names(newdf) = 1:nrows
```

Comment: Just realized that you wanted a column "seq" - I'll update my code.

Comment: New solution adds on the new "seq" column. Also it is much faster - rather than calling rbind for every row, you can calculate a group of rows (stored in tmpdf) and bind these to the newdf